# PdfStream.setData() in iText Object appends extra bytes at the beginning and at the end. How do I prevent appending extra bytes in the PdfStream?

Tags: pdf, itext

A stream is extracted from a PDF using iText library in JAVA, some manipulation is done to the stream and the resultant stream is used to replace the original stream. ps.setData() appends extra bytes at the beginning and at the end of the stream. On debugging ps does not contain the extra bytes, but on termination of the program the stream gets appended by extra bytes at the beginning as well as at the end which is reflected in the pdf. This is not reflected in the print statement at the last line. How should I prevent this?

```
byte[] b;       
                    
b = ((PdfStream) pdfobj).getBytes(false);
byte[] ciphertext = encryptstream(b, pdfobj.getIndirectReference().getObjNumber(), pdfobj.getIndirectReference().getGenNumber(), id);
System.out.println("Ciphertext "+new String(ciphertext,StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
PdfStream ps = (PdfStream) pdfobj;
ps.setData(ciphertext,false);
System.out.println(new String(ps.getBytes(),StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Required output

```
H!`hºB´0\çŽ|ZtÆ—¹ã)9"s”yhö]¿>öCš^•{¶ú³IˆÜÄà†þ   ^†ïˆE˜OôèÁö·Ë}û)³êäŠóó¥¨ÝÔRÔªªª
é£!ûÝPæ*#+õ(7f’ÀþtŽÃXwÓ“6¡pV¶™Y‰·ôn$·"LÌ€Xë*>1¬ryþ¶4©ðå–1šÆ*C1S‘ÆÓVG9šµÊz•[D¬˜¼ŽÍÈ{ëfÓPŠþ;úÿÌÄ¸ŠÏ–~¥É‘8
€Ó„–¶é=85d@ëÞ”/{õD¤Jä‹ÞpSVáŠ–ì°nMÊïoVœK)9S=!’“9Ê/ùØÙ1nÆ1-¤\ïµ"&!9d;R/Ês¿7çÌ|Zø‰åÊÕÏÅPôî tÝú!dž–Ö")Nà_r~™èé!3ÜÍÖ´ìg‰uÕ…¥Ý
```

Output obtained

```
xœ`ŸþH!`hºB´0\çŽ|ZtÆ—¹ã)9"s”yhö]¿>öCš^•{¶ú³IˆÜÄà†þ  ^†ïˆE˜OôèÁö·Ë}û)³êäŠóó¥¨ÝÔRÔªªª
é£!ûÝPæ*#+õ(7f’ÀþtŽÃXwÓ“6¡pV¶™Y‰·ôn$·"LÌ€Xë*>1¬ryþ¶4©ðå–1šÆ*C1S‘ÆÓVG9šµÊz•[D¬˜¼ŽÍÈ{ëfÓPŠþ;úÿÌÄ¸ŠÏ–~¥É‘8
€Ó„–¶é=85d@ëÞ”/{õD¤Jä‹ÞpSVáŠ–ì°nMÊïoVœK)9S=!’“9Ê/ùØÙ1nÆ1-¤\ïµ"&!9d;R/Ês¿7çÌ|Zø‰åÊÕÏÅPôî tÝú!dž–Ö")Nà_r~™èé!3ÜÍÖ´ìg‰uÕ…¥ÝP*®
```

Comment: *"ps.setData() appends extra bytes at the beginning and at the end of the stream."* - What bytes? Please show examples?

Comment: Example added for reference

Comment: Could it be that the stream is flate encoded? Does it have the **FlateDecode** filter? The extra bytes look like zlib additions...

Comment: Yes the stream is flate encoded. If those bytes are zlib additions, how to prevent those bytes from appending ?

Comment: Have you tried `((PdfStream) pdfobj).setCompressionLevel(CompressionConstants.NO_COMPRESSION)`?

Comment: Yes I've tried it, didn't help.